# I’m not sure how to make a UITableView Cell open a link in safari?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am very new to iOS development and Objective-C in general, and I’m not sure what to do here. Basically, I have a UITableView set up so that each cell gets a title and description (two labels placed inside the prototype cell). I can use an array to control which cell displays what text. However, now I want to use this same array system to make it so that each cell opens a different safari page.

Here’s my **TableViewController.h** file:

```
@interface MoreTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *Title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *Description;
```

Here’s my **TableViewController.m** file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _Title = @[@“Title1",
               @“Title2",
               @“Title3",];

    _Description = @[@“Description1",
                     @“Description2",
                     @“Description3",];

}
```

Here’s my **Cell.h** file:

```
@interface MoreCell : UITableViewCell

@property  (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *TitleLabel;
@property  (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *DescriptionLabel;
```

Here’s my **Cell.m** file:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

Using the storyboard editor in Xcode 5 I was able to link the **DescriptionLabel** and **TitleLabel** to some labels so that multiple cells could be created and the labels could be assigned based on the array.

Heres a screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/25rrez8y2071m63/Screen%20Shot%202014-07-19%20at%2012.49.02%20PM.png

My main goal is just to make each cell open a different webpage using an array like the one above.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

-Austin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In completion of Malex reply:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Get your url, eg: NSString *url = yourArray[indexPath.row];
    NSString *url = @"http://www.apple.com";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: url]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

delegate method and choose appropriate url from your _URL array which also must be defined in your

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```